# Geolocation Ionic 3 always return "{}"

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic3

I'm stuck with this problem. I'm not able to get the coordinates using [Ionic Geolocation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/).  Always return is "{}" .Anybody can help me? This is my code.

```
import { Geolocation, GeolocationOptions } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

 constructor(
  private geolocation: Geolocation,
  public platform: Platform,
) {}

this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
  this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options)
  .then((position) => {
      console.log('Geolocation successful', JSON.stringify( position));
      this.app.alertMsg(  JSON.stringify( position) );
     // let query = '?lat=' + position.coords.latitude + '&lng=' + position.coords.longitude;


  }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', JSON.stringify( error));
  });
 })
```

Comment: Yes, for geolocation only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova Geolocation plugin returning empty position object on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882035/cordova-geolocation-plugin-returning-empty-position-object-on-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at this.
[Cordova Geolocation plugin returning empty position object on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882035/cordova-geolocation-plugin-returning-empty-position-object-on-android) by Flock Dawson

> Apparently, the getCurrentPosition() function returns a 'special' object in Android, which evaluates to {} when using JSON.stringify(). If I outputted the raw return object to the console, it turned out it wasn't empty at all.

And according to https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/

you can get the latitude and longitude, etc. by

```
 this.app.alertMsg(position.coords.longitude + ' ' + position.coords.latitude);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try this one!